# Display different images in a separate <div> when mouse hover on different <a> tabs

Tags: html, jquery, css

my buttons are -

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs " id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a style="text-decoration:none" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" id="ps" role="tab" aria-selected="true">tab1</a>                                                                                               
                    <a style="text-decoration:none" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" id="pi" role="tab" aria-selected="false">tab2</a> 
                    <a style="text-decoration:none" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" id="ri" role="tab" aria-selected="false">tab3</a>                                                                                                                                                  
                    </div>
```

and i have 3 images which need to be displayed on each tab hover, mentioned above -

```
<div class="hide1"> <img src="img/image1.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; border: 1px solid #424242;"></div>
               <div class="hide2"> <img src="img/image2.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; border: 1px solid #424242;"></div>
               <div class="hide3"> <img src="img/image3.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; border: 1px solid #424242;"></div>
```

css i am using is -

```
div.hide1 { 
    display: none; 
    }           
    a#ps:hover + div.hide1 
    { 
    display: block; 
    } 
    div.hide2 { 
    display: none; 
    }           
    a#pi:hover + div.hide2
    { 
    display: block; 
    } 
    div.hide3 { 
    display: none; 
    }           
    a#ri:hover + div.hide3 
    { 
    display: block; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use **javascript** where that will help you alot to change the image by using one div "or many" that shows the images,so..

you don't need to make these three div's hide just by css make it's `position: absolute` , `z-index = 0` to `9` on depends, and then on a:hover using `@keyframe` to change the `z-index` or (I'm not sure ) by `@media`.
hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Zainab , i tried with it. Images are overlapping above each other that's it